# Is router incompatible with react-toolbox, or am I miss-using router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm trying to make a multipage mobile ui for my reactjs app. However, when trying to use react-router, I can't get any of my components to render. I'm following a tutorial for a very simple route implementation, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The below code renders just fine: (index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './component/App';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { overrideComponentTypeChecker } from 'react-toolbox';
import background from './component/Styles.css';
import { Router, hashHistory as history } from 'react-router';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('app');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#49c0f0';
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
    <App />
    </AppContainer>,
    rootEl
  );
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  overrideComponentTypeChecker((classType, reactElement) => (
    reactElement && (
      reactElement.type === classType
      || reactElement.type.name === classType.displayName
    )
  ));
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./component/App', render);
  }
}

render();
```

After changing the render portion of the code  to this the component stops rendering:

```
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
    <Router>
    <Route component={App} />
    </Router>
    </AppContainer>,
    rootEl
  );
};
```

Comment: You have not specified a path on your route

Comment: I tried adding a path and that didn't work either.

Comment: What version of react-router and react-toolbox do you use?

Comment: The latest one, I just installed it last week.